# How do I add a column to a Contribution Summary report which will show the date and amount of the most recent payment/donation?

Tags: civireport

When running a payment report using the Contribution summary,  along with the columns showing number of payments, payment aggregate and payment average, I would like to be able to see the date and amount of the last/most recent payment. This information can be separately gathered by running a Contribution detail report, but it is a lengthy process going through two separate spreadsheets when, ideally, I would want this information regularly, so having the data within the Contribution summary report who be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the summary fields extension:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields

It'll keep a calculated copy of the last contribution amount (and many other useful fields) as custom fields of the contact, making reporting like this much easier.

Because contributions are stored in a separate table, generating fields like 'last contribution' tends to be complicated and mixing it with other values isn't going to be well supported in most reports, but pulling in custom contact field values is almost always supported.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds just right, i will try it